# Unknown command-line option '--variant'

Tags: android, react-native

After upgrading React Native version from 0.57.8 to 0.59.3. I unable to build an app with the following command

```
./gradlew assemble --variant=release
```

it produces error

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Problem configuring task :@segment_analytics-react-native:assemble from command line.
> Unknown command-line option '--variant'.
```

I suppose the main change in Android build is a switch to

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1'
```

from

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'
```

Any ideas what should I do to be able to use `variant` option again?

**Edit:**

```
react-native run-android --variant=release
```

give me

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Task 'installRelease' not found in project ':app'.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like it was some mess after the upgrade. Clean project fix my issue.

```
Android Studio > Build > Clean Project
```

Comment: Nice work! Sometimes little things make a big mess!

Answer (score 3):

According to the official [document](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android), the command should be

```
react-native run-android --variant=release
```

2024 update(Thanks to @justice-mba :

the --variant option is now replaced with --mode. So,

```
react-native run-android --mode=release
```

Comment: yes, I'm actually using it. But I think `./gradlew assemble --variant=release` produce more useful information. Check my updated question.

Comment: What is your gradle version?

Comment: my version is gradle-4.10.2 from gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties

Comment: Can you share the build.gradle

Comment: Thanks for you help, I've resolved my issue. Check my answer.

Comment: 2024 update: the `--variant` option is now replaced with `--mode`. So, `react-native run-android --mode=release`